# How do I pass build optimisation when using `dub run`?

Tags: d, dub

Is it possible to use [D's O optimisation](https://dlang.org/dmd-windows.html#switch-) when using [`dub run` command line](https://dub.pm/commandline.html)?

The package manager is absolutely fantastic, and just wondering if it is possible to pass along the following switches.

`-O -release -inline -boundscheck=off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really never use those switches. dmd's optimizer is near useless, its inliner barely works, `-release` introduces undefined behavior, and `-boundscheck=off` introduces security holes to your application. There's a reason none of them are default!

If you want effective optimization and inlining, use gdc or ldc instead, as they are D's optimizing compilers.

That said, `dub` will pass those switches if you use `dub build -b release-nobounds`. See the options in the docs here:

https://dub.pm/commandline

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I looked into the [dub commandline page](https://dub.pm/commandline) 
 earlier and missed it. I can now see `-b` allows me to pass `release-nobounds`. I'll do as per your suggestion to use *gdc* or *ldc* instead of introducing security holes. Oh, I've purchased your book too, **D Cookbook**, and thanks for making it available.